# if cell in range then "yes"

Tags: excel, vba

Currently have the following formula in Excel:

```
=IF(AND(D3=Range(J:J);E3=Range(E:E));"Yes";"No")
```

However, this does not give the correct answer. The ask is:
If D3 is in column J and E3 is in the same line in column E, then Yes, if not, then no.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean if a cell in column J contains the text "D3"?

Comment: "*E3 is in the same line in column E*" This will always be the case... I'm not sure if I understand this part, can you please use an example?

Comment: "*If D3 is in column J*" - You can use `=IF(COUNTIF(I:I,D3)>0,"YES","NO")` and this will work

Comment: @Maldred I'm sure you mean `=IF(COUNTIF(J:J,D3)>0,"YES","NO")`

Comment: @Xabier Yes, correct my appologies

Answer (score 1):

A simple COUNTIFS function is ideal for this situation:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(J:J;D3;E:E;E3);"Yes";"No")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it might be easier to accomplish this using VBA (assumes you have headers in your sheet):

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'set this to your sheet name
Lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row 'check last row on column J
For i = 2 To Lastrow 'loop til last row
    If ws.Cells(i, "J").Value2 = ws.Range("D3").Value2 Then 'if D3 is in column J then
        If ws.Cells(i, "E").Value2 = ws.Range("E3").Value2 Then 'if E3 is in column E (same row as J was found) then
            ws.Cells(i, "H").Value2 = "Yes" 'add yes to column H, change this to where you want the answer yes/no
        Else
            ws.Cells(i, "H").Value2 = "No"
        End If
    Else
        ws.Cells(i, "H").Value2 = "No"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this formula:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(J:J,D3)>0,MATCH(D3,J:J)=MATCH(D3,E:E)),"Yes","No")
```

It checks if `D3` is in column J, and if so, it sees if the value of `D3` that's in Column J is the same row as value of `D3` in column J.

Answer (score 0):

Use the match function.  The match function returns the row of a matching lookup value.  If the two are equal, then they are in the same row.

```
=IF(MATCH(D3,J:J,)=MATCH(D3,E:E,),"YES","NO")
```